# How to chan "RoomDatabase and Retrofit" in RxJava

Tags: retrofit2, rx-java2, android-room

I'm using the Repository Pattern. 
I would like to implement logic that if there is no value in the internal DB returns the value of the Api Response and inserts it in the internal DB.

> Received internal DB Value (Single Type) 
>  Return final value if found, Request Server Api if not found 
>  Insert in internal DB (Completable Type) 
>  Return final value (Single Type)
>   
>  **If any of these processes call onError, the final return value of this logic shall be onError.**

```
fun getAllStudent(): Single<List<StudentEntity>> =
        cache.getAllStudent().onErrorResumeNext { getAllStudentRemote() }

private fun getAllStudentRemote(): Single<List<StudentEntity>> =
        remote.getAllMember()
            .map { memberData -> memberData.students }
            .map { studentList -> studentList.map { student -> studentMapper.mapToEntity(student) } }
            .doOnSuccess { studentEntityList -> cache.insertStudents(studentEntityList) }
```

This is how I tried. 
However, in the insert section, because it cannot subscribe, It cannot insert into internal DB or detect onError. 
How can I implement this logic? 
++  I'm sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to wait for `cache.insertStudents()` to complete, one thing you can do is to chain `cache.insertStudents()` into the stream using flatMap.

For example:

```
fun getAllStudent(): Single<List<StudentEntity>> =
        cache.getAllStudent().onErrorResumeNext { getAllStudentRemote() }

private fun getAllStudentRemote(): Single<List<StudentEntity>> =
        remote.getAllMember()
            .map { memberData -> memberData.students }
            .map { studentList -> studentList.map { student -> studentMapper.mapToEntity(student) } }
            .flatMap { studentEntityList -> 
                cache.insertStudents(studentEntityList) // Completable
                    .toSingleDefualt(studentEntityList) // Convert to Single<List<StudentEntity>>
            }
```

Also note that `.do...` operators are side-effect operators, and you should not do any operation that can affect the stream.